# Capturing input from presentation remote

Tags: c#, .net, input, io

I have a presentation remote that I use with power point. Windows recognizes it as a presentation remote. I have an application that I'd like to control using the remote. What type of messages should I be looking for as I am not having any luck with mouse and keyboard messages. Does .NET have a way of dealing with these devices either specifically or generically?

Comment: Did you happen to find an answer to your question?

Comment: @Tae-SungShin Not yet. I just worked around it since Word and other applications seem to support it just fine. I was hoping it was a simulated key press but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: What kind of remote do you use? It seems that Targus remote does the simulated key press.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin It's a Targus remote. Got it for a few bucks at Target.